# Why is a VS2010 Windows app failing to install on WinXP VMs (32bit and 64bit) on one Win7 PC but not on a different Win7 PC?

Tags: .net, windows, installation, virtual-machine

The Windows application I'm working on is written in C# VS2010. It has several prerequisites which are set to 'download from the same location as my application'.

I need to verify that it installs on 32bit and 64bit WinXP, Win7 and also on Windows 8. Given that I don't have 5 extra PCs handy I'm installing it on VMs.

It installs on Win7, both 32bit and 64bit. On WinXP though (both flavours) the prerequisites fail to install. For example, I get the message below, and if I then manually install MSXML 4 it fails on .NET3.5, saying the publisher can't be verified.

---

**Sample error message**

Setup has detected that the file 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\MSXML 4\msxml4.sp2.winxp.msi' has either changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt.

See the setup log file located at 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\install.log' for more information.

---

The kicker is that the same build installs on my colleague's 32bit WinXP VM (copy of same image) without problems.

The log file mentioned is no more informative than the error message. Here are the last few lines:

---

**Log File Extract**

EULA for components 'Windows Installer 4.5' was accepted.
EULA for components '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' was accepted.
EULA for components 'SQL Server 2008 R2 Express' was accepted.
Installation of components 'MSXML 4, Adobe Flash Player 11' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\"
Copying from 'C:\1.13.0248 - Release - English Only\MSXML 4\msxml4.sp2.winxp.msi' to 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\MSXML 4\msxml4.sp2.winxp.msi'
Verifying file integrity of C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\MSXML 4\msxml4.sp2.winxp.msi
Verifying file hash
Error: Setup has detected that the file 'C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\VSD2.tmp\MSXML 4\msxml4.sp2.winxp.msi' has either changed since it was initially published or may be corrupt.

---

The file mentioned as changed or corrupt wasn't in the destination when I went to look at it, which did indeed seem like a drastic change to the file, but on consulting Google I discovered that it would have been automatically deleted when the alleged corruption was discovered.

I've tried googling numerous combinations of the error message, 'VM install', etc but it's like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Following one slightly related post I tried setting some file types in the 'Local Group Policy Editor' on my PC, and loading up a fresh VM - no effect. It seems pointless to make policy editor changes in the VM itself, since the same image works unmodified for my colleague.

What am I missing here? I'm stumped. I've spent all day on this - it takes SO LONG to try each install. Any pointers would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You're probably right about the install.log file being unhelpful, but it would still be useful to us to see what is in there.

Comment: You're right Joel, my apologies. I have added the relevant (last) lines from the log file. Note that I have tried with several different builds, and have also reloaded a fresh VM at least three times.